# mkfs.ext4 not working on 19.1TB logical volume

Tags: lvm, ext4

I can not figure out why its not allowing me to put a filesystem on this logical volume, does anyone have a solution or troubleshoot for this?

```
root@Home-Pi:~# vgs
  VG                #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  VG_Remote_Storage   2   1   0 wz--n- 18.19t    0 


root@Home-Pi:~# lvs
  LV                VG                Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  LV_Remote_Storage VG_Remote_Storage -wi-a----- 18.19t                  


root@Home-Pi:~# wipefs -a /dev/mapper/VG_Remote_Storage-LV_Remote_Storage


root@Home-Pi:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/VG_Remote_Storage-LV_Remote_Storage 
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Creating filesystem with 4883200000 4k blocks and 305201152 inodes
Filesystem UUID: bbe76c30-9d69-4528-8c20-711801aca7de
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632, 
        2560000000, 3855122432

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): mkfs.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read 
        while trying to create journal


root@Home-Pi:~# fsck.ext4 -F /dev/VG_Remote_Storage/LV_Remote_Storage
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/VG_Remote_Storage/LV_Remote_Storage

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

root@Home-Pi:~#
```

Comment: mkfs.ext4 might be trying to format it with only 2^32 blocks (even with 4K blocks, 2^32*4096 is 16T, which is less than 19T).  It should automatically use 2^64 blocks when required, but "stuff happens" so try it with `mkfs.ext4 -O 64bit ...`.    See `man ext4` for info on '64bit' and other filesystem features.  Alternatively, try XFS rather than ext4.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using btrfs or zfs instead of lvm + ext4/xfs.  i personally wouldn't use a fs without error-detection and correction on a filesystem anywhere near that large - that's just asking for silent corruption and data-loss.

Comment: BTW, does the `root@Home-Pi:~#` prompt indicate you're running on some kind of raspberry pi?  If that's the case, it's probably running a 32-bit version of linux (which may be why mkfs.ext4 isn't using the `64bit` fs feature).    More significantly, an rpi is **not** a good choice for any kind of file server - USB is not a good interface for drives.  You'd be much better off buying/building/scrounging some old PC with an amd64 cpu and at least 3 or 4 SATA3 interfaces (it's not hard to find ancient stuff like this being given away for free).

Comment: You should rework this as a answer and i will accept. I believe you are correct. And yes, i am running Raspberry pi 4 4GB, which is however a 64 ARM. I am successful in making a ext4 partition under 16TB and mounting. I can create a xfs for the entire 19.1TB, but then i receive errors when mounting that the fs to too big. Quick googling seems me to believe this is common with 32 bit systems, which confuse me because my pi is 64bit. Any further insight on this? uname -m reports armv7l

Comment: armv7l is actually 32 bit, hmm.  This is making more sense now.. my assumption was wrong. Also, im considering your zfs recommendation, but i know nothing about it. Still looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raspberry pi is running a 32-bit version of linux, so mkfs.ext4 is formatting the filesystem with 2^32 blocks, which (with a 4k block size) limits the filesystem to a maximum size of 16 TiB.    XFS on 32-bit linux is also [limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS#Capacity) to 16 TiB.

Interestingly, the [Raspberry Pi 4 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) has a Broadcom BCM2711 which **is** a 64-bit ARM v8 quad-core CPU.  The default OS for all models of raspberry pis is 32-bit, and IIRC even raspbian is 32-bit.  Probably so they only have to maintain one version of it rather than a 32-bit and a 64-bit version.   64-bit distros **are** available for rpis - but I don't know anywhere near enough about them to recommend one.  Google is your friend here, or perhaps try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

On 32 bit, your only real option is to reduce the partition size down to 16 TiB.  The remainder can be used as a 2nd partition of about 3 TiB.

In comments, I suggested using [ZFS](https://zfsonlinux.org/) - unfortunately, zfsonlinux requires a 64-bit linux kernel as it is [unstable on 32-bit](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/FAQ#32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems).  I also suggested btrfs, but it also has [limitations](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/FAQ#32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems) on 32-bit and is not recommended.

---

My final suggestion was to acquire a PC with an amd64 CPU and use that to build your file server.

These can be picked up cheap, or even free, and even a 10+ year old machine will make a far better file server than a raspberry pi - it will have multiple SATA3 ports (use one for an SSD for the boot + OS drive, or two in mdadm RAID-1; and 2 or more ports for your 19TiB storage), at least 4GB RAM (and room for expansion - the more memory a file server has, the better it performs), and it can run a 64-bit Linux so can format a 64bit ext4 or XFS, or use ZFS or btrfs without problem.

Your drives would be on SATA ports and your network interface(s) would be on PCI-e  - both of which are faster, far superior (and far more reliable) for that purpose than USB.

(BTW, you can use a partition on the SSD(s) to cache the hard disks.  ZFS calls this Layer 2 ARC or L2ARC, and for other filesystems [bcache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcache) is part of the kernel)

The only downside is that a PC would take more space, and use more power than a raspberry pi.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome, detailed, researched answer. I believe you kind of imply that the Ethernet interface is over USB: I think that, on the Raspberry Pi 4, it is not. Your point still stands.